# fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros-kinetic, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a package using `catkin_create_pkg` on PC  where I have previously installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ROS kinetic. But  I am trying to compile the cpp file included in the created package I get the following error

```
my@my-MS-7972:~/catkin_ws/src/sample_opencv/src$ g++ test_cv_bridge.cpp
test_cv_bridge.cpp:1:21: fatal error: ros/ros.h: no such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

looks like it does not see any of the header files included in my cpp file.

Edit: This is what I added to my package.xml

```
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend><build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend><build_depend>image_transport</build_depend><build_depend>roscpp</build_depend><build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend><build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend><build_export_depend>cv_bridge</build_export_depend><build_export_depend>image_transport</build_export_depend><build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend><build_export_depend>sensor_msgs</build_export_depend><build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend><exec_depend>cv_bridge</exec_depend><exec_depend>image_transport</exec_depend><exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend><exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend><exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
```

here is the `Cmakelist.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(sample_opencv)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
make_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(sample_opencv)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(cat
## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a exec_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   sensor_msgs#   std_msgs
# )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES sample_opencv
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/sample_opencv.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
add_executable(sample_opencv_node src/test_cv_bridge.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(sample_opencv_node
  ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_sample_opencv.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

and here is how Im including my header files

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300313/fatal-error:-ros/ros.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Tommy Hay](https://answers.ros.org/users/36494/tommy-hay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lalten](https://answers.ros.org/users/25550/lalten/) on 2018-08-11**:
Did you

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

See http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

**Comment by [Tommy Hay](https://answers.ros.org/users/36494/tommy-hay/) on 2018-08-11**:
I do these step ,still have same problem

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-12**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd is correct.

Also: this post is a duplicate of #q295301.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at the [Building Packages tutorial here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages), you need to use `catkin_make` to build a package (or a node within it). You're trying to use gcc with only the standard c++ headers and libraries so the compiler cannot find the ROS headers.

Since ROS is a very complex multi-language system the catkin built tool is used to automate the process.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0